# java regular expression - match all strings except few strings

Tags: java, regex

I have these strings in an array and I want to iterate this array and find those who match (one line per match check).
The thing is, I can't find the right regex.

```
Bird
Cat
Dog
Fish
CatDog
DogCat
```

Currently, with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) (damn nice software!!), I have this regex:

```
(?!Cat\b)\b\w+
```

I want to add the "Dog" to it so in one regex match try I'll get a match result, you know, like an OR operator.
I want it to check if "Cat" or "Dog" or "Fish" is there in one go.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this your actual problem or a simplified version of it? In the case where you're looking for literal strings and not obscure representations that can take on variable froms you're better off using methods like `.contains()`, `.equals()` or the like on a collection

Comment: @TheCapn - `contains()` and `equals()` will probably result in more readable code but I would expect regex to be more efficient for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\b(?!(?:Bird|Cat|Dog|Fish|CatDog|DogCat)\b)\w+
```

The `|` character is an OR operator in regex.